# Install MySQL package in R

Tags: r

I have tried to install MySQL package in R But unable to install package properly. Here is the code I have used

```
install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')
```

I am getting error like

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Techrains/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 165363 bytes (161 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 161 Kb

* installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ...
** package 'RMySQL' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'C:/Users/Techrains/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RMySQL'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\Techrains\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ihccf\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Techrains\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" C:\Users\TECHRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ihccf/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("RMySQL", type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am new to R. Can anyone help me out, would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First install MySQL itself (getting it from MySQL site is preferred) and copy any dll files found in the installation into the MySQL bin subdirectory.  Then read the INSTALL file that comes with the RMySQL package.

Comment: I have installed MySQL 5.0. Can you please more elaborate @G.Grothendieck

Comment: Refer this 
http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/

Answer (score 1):

This may seem like a silly question, but did you try simply:

```
install.packages("RMySQL")
```

I just installed the package using the above line and it tried pulling the package from the CRAN library:

```
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/RMySQL_0.10.4.zip'
```

Which is different from the URL your code tried. Additonally the package ws 1.8MB from the CRAN library where yours was only 161KB, which leads me to believe something is off with the file your code is downloading.

Perhaps first try removing the package you downloaded to by using:

```
remove.packages("RMySQL")
```

Edit: And I just realized this was asked over a year ago, oops. I will leave my answer here anyway.